# 'default' is not exported by helloWorldNew.js LWC

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-web-components

I am trying to use a JS file which is within same folder structure like below. When i am trying to deploy, it is giving error

> LWC1002: Error in module resolution: 'default' is not exported by
>   helloWorldNew.js

Does LWC doesn't support this kind of structure.

```
Hello World - 
            - helloWorld.html
            - helloWorld.js
            - helloWorld.js-meta.xml
            - helloWorldnew.js
```

helloWorldnew.js

```
const gAlert = (function () {
    alert('Extra JS file found');
}).call({});
export { gAlert };
```

helloWorld.js

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import helloWorldNew from "./helloWorldNew.js";

export default class HelloWorld extends LightningElement {

    @track result;
    getAlertFunction() {
        this.result = helloWorldNew.gAlert;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a named export, so you would need to import it as such:

```
import { gAlert } from './helloWorldNew.js';
```

The `{}` makes it a named export, versus a default export. Alternatively, you can make it a default export:

```
export default gAlert;
```

Which would then support a default import:

```
import gAlert from './helloWorldNew.js';
```